# why is there an error on my empty activity project on android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xml-error

when I open a new project it comes with an error saying: Element androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout must be declared and here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried to rebuild project, clean project ,make project and sync projects with Gradle file I even try to recreate projects many times but nothing changed.

Comment: okay I changed it to code can you try it

Comment: I checked every thing its all right I just don't know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Gradle if constains this two lines :

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
```